# Cannot get Button to activate code behind in ASP.NET / C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, razor, razor-pages

I am unable to get my button to activate my code behind. I have tried adding `asp-source`, `asp-action`, `runat`, and every time my `onclick` does not work and I get the error:

> 47 Uncaught ReferenceError: PlayerHit is not defined
> at HTMLUnknownElement.onclick

This is my markup:

```
<asp:Button runat= "server" id="butAddPlayerCard" onclick="PlayerHit">Hit2</asp:Button>
<button onclick="PlayerHit" id="finalButton" runar>Final</button>
<button ID="Button2" onclick="PlayerHit" runat="server" Class="btn btn-primary btn-light">Hit</button>
```

I just need one button but this is to show what I have tried.

Code behind:

```
public void PlayerHit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DeckAction deckAction = new DeckAction();
    deckAction.AddCard(deck, PlayersHand);

    foreach (var item in PlayersHand)
    {
        if ((item.Values) == 0)
        {
            var cardValue = item.Values;
        }
    }
}
```

This code is in the main class of the file.

Comment: `runat="server"` indicates webforms - but that isn't supported in ASP.NET Core ...... so you need to be a bit clearer about **what** you're really using, and what technology is involved here....

Comment: I suggest you could share the whole page's codes and the button codes. This code is used for webform not Razor pages, they are different, please share more details information so that we could continue working on it.

Comment: You indicated on the deleted answer that you are using Razor Pages, not Web Forms. What are you using as a source for learning about Razor Pages?

Answer (score 1):

According to [`Button.OnClick`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclick?view=netframework-4.8) method, it should be `OnClick` but not `onclick`. And use the Web form control.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" OnClick="PlayerHit" runat="server" 
            Class="btn btn-primary btn-light">Hit</asp:Button>
```

Comment: Thank you for correcting my spelling error, however I tried this aswell and it throws the same error.(playerhit not defined)